# How to request Flink job metrics between start-time and end-time?

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to use Flinks monitoring REST API in order to retrieve some metrics for a specific time period.

Looking at the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/monitoring/metrics.html#system-metrics), I can find the metrics of the job by navigating to http://hostname:8081/jobs/:jobid and I have the following:

```
{ 
   "jid":"692c1d818afb77daaca891484e0b6a7g",
   "name":"myjob",
   "isStoppable":false,
   "state":"RUNNING",
   "start-time":1570552858876,
   "end-time":-1,
   "duration":62639599,
   "now":1570615498475,
   ...
```

I would like to know if there is a method for requesting metrics from a specific `start-time` and `end-time`, the documentation does not mention if this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that  you can achieve  that via Rest API.

But you can defiantly [export](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#reporter)  flink metrics  for further analysis.